# Numeric Precision Rounding Artifacts with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, odbc, arbitrary-precision

We have an application that is attempting a bulk insert into a table within a postgresql (9.1 I think, I don't have access helping coworker troubleshoot remotely). A trace shows the raw values are generated correctly and handed off to the ODBC correctly.

The problem comes in with a column defined as NUMERIC but did not have scale or precision defined. There seem to be 'random' rounding artifacts. Sometimes rounds up, sometimes down with no relationship to number of decimal places. This is seen when values from the bulk insert are then queried.

I know it can cause issues with strings but not sure if it matters with numeric data types. The database is windows 1252 encoded and they are using the Unicode postgresql driver. Finally just some FYI its on a 32 bit windows VM with what looks like the default config_file parameters.

Question is what would/could be the cause of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The data type [`numeric` is an arbitrary precision data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL), not a floating point type like `float8` (`double precision`) or `float4` (`real`). I.e., it stores decimal digits that are handed to it without any rounding whatsoever. Numbers are reproduced identically. Only the exact format may depend on your locale or settings of the middleware and client.

The fact that the precision and scale were not set lets the `numeric` column do that with almost**<sup>1</sup>** no limitation.

[**<sup>1</sup>** Per documentaion:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)

> up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point.

The gist of it: you can rule out the Postgres  data type `numeric` as source for the rounding effect. I don't know about the rest, especially since you did not provide exact version numbers, demo values or a reproducible test case.
My shot in the dark would be that ODBC might treat the number like a floating point type. Maybe an outdated version?